# How to access function defined in namespace in other .cc file

Tags: c++

I have a file named `test.cc`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int doit(){
    return 4;
}

namespace abc {
    int returnIt(int a){
        return a;
    }
}
```

I can use doit(), but how can I use this function in namespace in my `main.cc` without using .h file:

```
using namespace abc;
int doit();
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    cout<<returnIt(3)<<endl; // print 3
    cout<<doit();            // print 4
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"How can I use this function in my main.cc like this without using .h file"_ Why would you want this? What's your use case? Sounds like a XY-problem.

Comment: I want to test functions written in apollo(https://github.com/ApolloAuto/apollo/blob/be07d2b6344ee55834eafbd85df7374b93bb51ea/modules/perception/camera/test/camera_lib_obstacle_tracker_common_test.cc)

Comment: Instead of using .h you can include .cc in main.cc if you remove that .cc from the build command.

Answer (score 1):

You can call functions by first declaring them. Example:

```
namespace abc {
    int returnIt(int a); // function declaration
}

int main() {
     abc::returnIt(3);     // the declared function can now be called
```

Note that the declaration must be exactly the same as used elsewhere in the program. To achieve identical declarations across translation units, it is conventional to put the declaration into a separate file (called a header) and include that file using the pre-processor whenever the declaration is needed.

Comment: What if I have two files?

Comment: @user7341005 number of files is irrelevant.

Comment: @user7341005 think of this as making your own header. Sooner or later you need the declarations whether they are embedded in the source file or in a header file. If you don't have a header, or can't use the provided header, I think the best answer is to make your own replacement header.

Comment: If namespace abc in one file and main in the other, you can't run it correctly

Comment: @user7341005 You have to reproduce the namespace as well.

Answer (score -1):

All you need is to simply write the functions before the main function. That way, the compiler has processed the function prototypes by the time it encounters them in main and can validate the function call.

```
int doit()
{
  return 4;
}

int returnIt(int a)
{
    return a;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  cout<<returnIt(3)<<endl; // print 3
  cout<<doit();            // print 4
  return 0;
}
```

In general, avoid `using namespace;`. It makes for code that can be broken or be rendered less readable due to incorrect variable/function usage. That is because too many symbols can occupy the same (global) scope.

If another library needs to used, as user4581301 pointed out, then it may be simpler to use eerorika [answer/method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54660318/4357841).

Comment: Hard to do this if the functions in question are in a different file or a library.

Comment: downvote police? anyway, edited the answer to point to eerorika if the OP actually needs it.

Comment: The Asker wants to know how to access functions in another file or library without having a header. You answer this by throwing out the other file  or library. That completely misses the point of the question rendering this answer "Not Useful".

Comment: imo, that is your opinion. for quick prototyping for an obvious newbie, my answer is sufficient. additionally, you infer that he NEEDS the entire file/library. that is not a valid assumption for me.

Comment: Quoting asker: *I want to test functions written in apollo(github.com/ApolloAuto/apollo/blob/…)*

Comment: that's a comment (while I was answering) and, regardless, my answer still stands as was. I wrote an explanation, gave some contextual advise and an alternate method. I even later edited it to reflect your wants. without preprocessing directives, he'd need to link code dynamically.